# Peewee row level blocking

Tags: mysql, locking, peewee

I'm currently using [Peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee) as an ORM in my project. In my current situation, I have some processes each having a database connection. All of these processes need to access a **certain table simultaneously**. I'm looking for some way to make them coordinated **without using a central controller**. For this, when a row is read by a process, it must get locked and **no other process could read that row**. Blocked processes should continue with other non-blocked rows.

I searched around and found that MySql already has an internal locking mechanism, described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-locking.html) and apparently it must be used on **indexed** columns to behave as expected ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665093)). But I couldn't find anything related in the peewee documents. Is there any extension providing these feature? Or should i write raw SQL queries containing `FOR Update` clause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Peewee supports using the FOR UPDATE clause, and I think this is probably what you want. It won't prevent other clients from reading, but it will prevent modifications for as long as the transaction holding the lock is open.

Ex:

```
with db.atomic():
    # lock note.
    note = Note.select().where(Note.id == 123).for_update().get()
    # As long as lock is held no other client can modify note.
```

Comment: Does it support `NOWAIT` or `SKIP LOCKED` ? I can't find anything in the documents. Another question, you said that "using `FOR UPDATE` won't prevent other clients from reading", so how can i prevent these reads ? I know that `SELECT ... FOR SHARE` are blocked but simple `SELECT` queries are not blocked.

Comment: BTW, how isolation level of a transaction can be specified in `db.atomic()`?

Comment: .for_update('for share nowait') -- or .for_update('for update nowait') - etc